# Type cast in Pointer arithmetic for two dimensional array(C)

Tags: c, arrays, casting

Do I need to do type casting when I want to index a specific array element of a two dimensional array manually with pointer arithmetic.If so why? Here's what I mean:

```
float *p;
float balance[5][2]={2.34, 
5.66,7.85,12.56,9.87,76.22,56.55,21.02,66.12,10.001};
p=(float *) balance;   //Do I need this type casting and if so why?    
printf("%.2f",*(p+(3*2)+1));
```

Comment: Only if you want to treat the 2D array as a 1D array...

Answer (score 0):

Balance is a 2D array that is an array of arrays. It will decay like any array to a pointer to its first element... but that element is still an array and not a float!

That is the reason why you need a cast here, but in fact casting a pointer to an array to a pointer to its first element is not really standard wise. The correct way is to dereference `balance`: it will be an 1D array which will nicely decay to a pointer to the first float:

```
p = *balance;    // no cast required here
```

That being said, on a pedantic point of view, the next line (`*(p+(3*2)+1)`) aliases a 2D 2x5 array to an 1D array of size 10. The result is undefined per the standard as soon as the index is larger that the row size here 2. Of course all common implementation allow it for compatibility with old code, but you really should wonder why you need it and avoid that if you can.

The correct and conformant way would be:

```
float (*pp)[2];
float balance[5][2] = { 2.34,
    5.66,7.85,12.56,9.87,76.22,56.55,21.02,66.12,10.001 };
pp = balance;
printf("%.2f\n", pp[3][1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I am learning to code and it was written in a book.I was having a hard time.Now it makes sense.

Comment: What if you did `float *p = &(balance[0][0]);`?  You can use pointer arithmetics with it.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito `&(balance[0][0])` is the same thing as `*balance`: a pointer to the first element of the first row. The only problem is that the standard only defines pointer arithmetics **inside** an array (or one past end) and that here the float arrays only have size 2.